# How can I use Zigpy in Python to create a standalone simulated device and connect it to an existing Zigbee network?

Tags: python-3.x, zigbee

I am trying to find examples in Python of using a Zigbee stack library such as Zigpy to create a simulated device (such as a thermostat or a bulb or the likes) and connect it to an already established Zigbee network.

Does anyone have any examples of doing something like this?

I have already tried looking through the Zigpy github repo for example and have found that you can simulate a device but its then just added to the gateway already created by Zigby rather than a stand alone network which is what I am trying to do.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.